# Possible to show the absolute addresses within shared libraries in a back trace in GDB?

Tags: gdb

When showing a call stack that contains dynamic library functions, I want to know the actual locations of the functions in the call stack within the libraries - not the addresses relative to the mapped address.

I know that I can manually calculate this for each call by running `info shared` and then subtract the offset for where the library was mapped into. But is there an automated way to do this?

This seems like a common problem to me so I just feel that there has to be someone out there who has had this problem before and has a handy solution ready :). I didn't find any scripts that do this which is why I'm posting this.

To illustrate the problem in case it isn't clear enough above:

I've set a breakpoint in `write()` and then show the callstack using `bt`.

```
Breakpoint 2, 0x00007ffff7eb1790 in write () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7eb1790 in write () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7e4185d in _IO_new_file_write () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7e40bbf in new_do_write () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7e429d9 in __GI__IO_do_write () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7e42db3 in __GI__IO_file_overflow () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7e37be2 in puts () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#6  0x0000555555555050 in main ()
(gdb) info maps
Undefined info command: "maps".  Try "help info".
(gdb) info shared
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7fd5000  0x00007ffff7ff3784  Yes (*)     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007ffff7de7450  0x00007ffff7f3083f  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
(gdb)
```

Here I want to convert e.g. `#0  0x00007ffff7eb1790 in write () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6` into `0xca340` automatically or actually `0x22450 + 0xca340` since the `.text` section starts at `0x22450` in that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion, Tom.

Here is the filter I came up with. It's a bit hacky since I couldn't find a neat way to 1. get the start address of the loaded libraries in a nice way, and 2. had to use objdump to get the .text section of the libraries.

```
import gdb
from gdb.FrameDecorator import FrameDecorator
import subprocess


class SharedFrameFilter():

    textOffsets = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "shared_filter"
        self.priority = 100
        self.enabled = True
        self.textOffsets = {}

        # Register this frame filter with the global frame_filters
        # dictionary.
        gdb.frame_filters[self.name] = self

    def getTextOffset(self, libName):
        if libName in self.textOffsets:
            return self.textOffsets[libName]

        out = subprocess.Popen([
            "objdump",
            "--section-headers",
            "--section=.text",
            libName
        ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

        lines = out.decode("utf-8").split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            if not ".text" in line:
                continue
            cols = line.split()
            startAddr = int(cols[3], 16)

            self.textOffsets[libName] = startAddr
            return startAddr

    def filter(self, frame_iter):
        for frame in frame_iter:
            address = frame.address()
            libName = gdb.solib_name(address)
            if libName == None:
                yield frame
                continue

            absoluteAddress = 0
            shared = gdb.execute("info shared", False, True)
            for line in shared.split('\n'):
                cols = line.split()
                try:
                    int(cols[0], 16)
                except:
                    continue

                if cols[4] != libName:
                    continue

                libStart = int(cols[0], 16)
                absoluteAddress = address - libStart + \
                    self.getTextOffset(libName)

                break

            frame.filename_orig = frame.filename
            frame.filename = lambda: "0x%08x in %s" % (
                absoluteAddress, frame.filename_orig())
            yield frame


SharedFrameFilter()
```

Usage in gdb:

```
(gdb) source SharedFrameFilter.py
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7eb1790 in write () at 0x000ec790 in /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7e4185d in _IO_new_file_write () at 0x0007c85d in /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7e40bbf in new_do_write () at 0x0007bbbf in /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7e429d9 in __GI__IO_do_write () at 0x0007d9d9 in /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7e42db3 in __GI__IO_file_overflow ()
    at 0x0007ddb3 in /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7e37be2 in puts () at 0x00072be2 in /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#6  0x0000555555555050 in main ()
```

Comment: "get the start address of the loaded libraries in a nice way" - there's a bug open about being able to get the section offsets from python, but needless to say nobody has implemented this yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do this.

One possible way to implement this for yourself would be to write a [frame filter](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Frame-Filter-API.html#Frame-Filter-API) in Python.  The idea here would be to have the filter notice when a frame comes from a shared object, and in those cases return a new frame with a modified address.  I am not sure if you can make this print the `0x22450 + 0xca340` form in the address output (if not it seems like something worth a gdb feature request), but you could print the unadorned address, or stuff extra information into the function- or file-name field.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I implemented a hacky filter that I posted as the answer below, but it seems to do the job just fine.